# How To Select row count From database with Where Conditions?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

How To Use where condition to get rowcount from database ? where and whereArgs parameter aren't defined and writing variables in query didn't work

```
 Future<int>GetRows(String Username,String Password) async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(
    await dbClient.rawQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $Table WHERE $CoulmnUserName = $Username AND 
         $CoulmnPassword = $Password",
       )
    );
  }
```

In getting Rows

```
int Row = await db.GetRows(_data.Username,_data.Password);
```

Row == 0

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQLite parameter (`?`) when testing for String value in a where clause. Something like this should work:

```dart
Future<int> getRowCount(String username, String password) async {
  var dbClient = await db;

  var result = await dbClient.query(table,
      columns: ['COUNT(*)'],
      where: '$columnUsername = ? AND $columnPassword = ?',
      whereArgs: [username, password]);

  return firstIntValue(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try below code:-

```
Future<int>GetRows(String Username,String Password) async{
  var dbClient = await db;

  var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $Table WHERE $CoulmnUserName = $Username AND $CoulmnPassword = $Password");

  return result.length;
}
```